# Python Requests Library not utilising proxy

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I'm experiencing some difficulty getting requests to utilise the proxy address when requesting a website. No error is returned but by getting the script to return http://ipecho.net/plain, I can see my own IP, not that of the proxy.

```
import random
import requests
import time

def proxy():        
    proxy = (random.choice(proxies)).strip()
    print("selected proxy: {0}".format(proxy))
    url = 'http://ipecho.net/plain'
    data = requests.get(url, proxies={"https": proxy})
    print(data)
    print("data returned: {0}".format(data.text))

proxies = []
with open("proxies.txt", "r") as fi:
    for line in fi:
        proxies.append(line)

while True:
    proxy()
    time.sleep(5)
```

The structure of the proxies.txt file is as follows:

```
https://95.215.111.184:3128
https://79.137.80.210:3128
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL you are passing is `http` and you only provide an `https` proxy key. You need to create a key in your `proxies` dictionary for both `http` and `https`. These can point to the same value.

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://proxy.example.com', 'https': 'http://proxy.example.com'}
data = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```